# Have you ever wondered do animals also think like we humans do?

Tags: socializing

this question always pop in my mind that what my pets would be thinking or do they also think like we do. i know animals also feel emotions but i dont know if they also have ability to think or not. Have you ever wondered what goes on in an animal's mind? What kinds of thoughts it has, or whether it can be sad or happy? Do they think like people do?

Comment: lots of people do wonder about this and pets can be sad-happy-frustrated.but i do not think it is possible to answer what they do think about.i am not even sure how people think or if all people do think in the same way,pets can often show the owner what they want(by walking to the door they can comunicate that they wants to go outside)but the reason a pet do have for this is unknown but we can guess.

Comment: Related https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/what-if-anything-sets-humans-apart-from-other-species

Comment: Have a look at this [TED talk about what animals are thinking and feeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wkdH_wluhw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do think in a way that is similar and comparable, but not quite the same.

> Life is very vivid to animals. In many cases they know who they are.
>   They know who their friends are and who their rivals are. They have
>   ambitions for higher status.  They compete. But many animals express
>   empathy for each other. There are documented stories of elephants
>   finding people who were lost. In one case, an old woman who couldn’t
>   see well, got lost and was found the next day with elephants guarding
>   her. They had encased her in sort of a cage of branches to protect her
>   from hyenas. That’s seems extraordinary to us but it comes naturally
>   to elephants.

https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/07/150714-animal-dog-thinking-feelings-brain-science/

> ... Grandin examines the surprising similarities between an animal’s mind and an autistic mind—her own. “Autistic people,” she writes, “are closer to animals than normal people are.” This may sound like a cruel judgment, the sort of thing a cold-hearted clinician would say, but it isn’t. It’s an acute observation, all the more important because it comes from an autistic person. Her autism, Grandin suggests, puts her somewhere between normal human mentality and animal mentality, not as a matter of IQ but as a matter of perception and emotion. Being closer to animals isn’t necessarily a bad thing. After all, that’s what makes Grandin such an uncanny translator of animal behavior.

http://discovermagazine.com/2005/may/what-do-animals-think

> "These data suggest that not only do some animals have a subjective take on the suitability of the option they are evaluating for their goal, they possess a subjective, internal signal regarding their confidence in this take that can be deployed to select amongst different options," he wrote.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/11/171101151206.htm